# REST API integration in PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, rest, restful-url

My client has got some `RESTful` services written in `ASP.net` and front end code in `PHP`. He is providing me `DTO` classes and `API` url. Can anyone help me how to call these `API` services from `PHP`?
I do not know how to make use of `DTO` classes in `PHP`

Answer (score 1):

The DTO classes will just specify the contract. I would imagine they will map to JSON objects returned by the service (although you will want to check the serialization format).

You should look into deserializing JSON to PHP objects:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Something like

```
$url="http://www.website.com/api/object/1";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json);
```

It doesnt seem trivial to decode to a specific class but you could declare a class for each DTO in PHP and instantiate the appropriate class from the client code and populate it with the data on the dynamic object that json_decode() returns.